# Issue with `npm start`: ERROR watch EMFILE although open files limit = 65536

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, osx-yosemite

`ulimit -a` log:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Although I am still getting EMFILE error while `npm start`.

> react-native@0.3.11 start /node_modules/react-native
>   ./packager/packager.sh

```
 ===============================================================
 |  Running packager on port 8081.       
 |  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS         
 |  projects. Feel free to close this tab and run your own      
 |  packager instance if you prefer.                              
 |                                                              
 |     https://github.com/facebook/react-native                 
 |                                                              
 ===============================================================
```

Looking for JS files in /

React packager ready.

```
 ERROR  watch EMFILE
{"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"watch"}
Error: watch EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1172:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1198:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:144:20)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:351:12)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at /node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to install **watchman**, here is how you can do it:

**Installing on OSX via Homebrew**

```
brew update
brew install watchman
```

**Installing from source**

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I was having the same issue and it was driving me crazy

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. I was looking for this. I just started with react-native on android and couldn't find anyone with similar issues. 

After editing every damn process/file limit config I could find I was still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are using "/" for your node server's root, so there are too many files under the root which leads to the error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's looking for file in correct folder:

    /Users/user/workspace/mobile/project

leads to this as well